# When is $\frac{a}{n} = n^a$ true?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Title says it all really, I am trying to figure out if theres a situation where 
$\frac{a}{n} = n^a$ is true or if this is impossible.
This is not realy from somewhere, just for the sake of curiosity.

Comment: $a=n=1{}{}{}{}$

Comment: $a/n = n^a \implies a*n/n = n^{a+1} \implies a = n^{a+1}$. which means...er....  $log_a a = (a+1) \log_a n \implies \log_a n = 1/(a+1) \implies n = a^{1/(a+1)}$.  So $a = 1, n=1$ is a solution.  $a = 2; n=\sqrt[3] a$ is a solution.  Etc.  Should be a solution for all a > 0.

Comment: @Wojowu that's one.  2/n = n^2 => 2 = n^3 => n = cube_root(2) is another.

Comment: Or to put it simply "n equals the a+1 th root of a" for any positive a.

Comment: What about integer solutions?

Comment: Integer solutions?  a needs to be a perfect a + 1 power.  If a > 1 we need $k^{a+1} = a$ but if $k > 1$ then $k^{a+1} =k*k*.... > k+k+... = (a+1)k > a$.  If $k < 0$ well... a = -2 then n = -1/2 I think works... $-2 = -1/2^{-1}$ but I'm sure it's the only one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\frac an = n^a \implies$

$a = n^{a+1} \implies $

$1 = \log_a a = \log_a n^{a+1} = (a +1 ) \log_a n \implies$

$\frac 1{a+1} = \log_a n \implies$

$n = a^{\frac 1{a+1}}$

So for all positive $a$, $n$ is solvable.  As $0/0$ (as well as $0^0$) are undefined $n = a = 0$ is not a solution (despite $0 = 0^1$).

For $a < 0$ it gets a little more complicated.

If $n > 0$ then $a/n < 0$ while $n^a > 0$ so $n < 0$.

But $n <0$ implies $a/n > 0$ so $(-|n|)^a > 0$ so $a = -p/q$ must be that $p$ is even.  (Remember: negative numbers to irrational powers are not defined.) And as $\gcd (p,q) =1$, $q$ must be odd.

Then $n = a^{1/(a+ 1)} = a^{q/(q-p)}$.

Example: $a = -2/3; n = (-2/3)^{3}$. And $a/n = \frac 1{(2/3)^2} = (-3/2)^2 = ((-3/2)^3)^{2/3} = ((-2/3)^3)^{-2/3} = n^a$

Or $a = -2; n=-1/2$ and $a/n = 4 = (-2)^2 = (-1/2)^{-2}$.

Or $a = -4/3; n = (-4/3)^{-1/3} = -\sqrt[3]{3/4}$.

etc.

Comment: When did $0^0$ get a value?  (Relevant for your "$a=0=n$".)

Comment: @EricTowers  Are you denying that $0/0 = 0^0$?  ;)  ... Yes, I *did* edit my answer long before your comment.  $0/0$ and $0^0$ aren't defined but $0 = 0^1$ is a true statement ...(which is why I made such a blunder.)

Comment: Awsome! Can you solve for a too?

Comment: You can select $a$ to be any positive real number.  You can also select a to be certain negative rational numbers:  either an negative even integer or a rational numer where 1/(a + 1) in its lowest terms has an odd integer in its denominator. ... which I *think* means if $a = p/q$ $a < 0$ then p and q most have one even and one odd.  I haven't checked that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $n=a=1$ is an easy solution.  For $n \not \in \{0,1\}$, there is also $a = \frac{-W_{k}(-n \ln n)}{\ln n}$, where $k \in \Bbb{Z}$, $W$ is the [Lambert function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html), which has a branch cut discontinuity (usually taken to run along the negative real axis from $-\infty$ to either $-1/\mathrm{e}$ or $0$, depending on your intended use), and $W_k$ is a value of $W$ on a different sheet of its continuation through the cut.

For instance, with $n=10$, the equation holds for $a \in \{\dots, -0.0642696 - 11.5948 \mathrm{i}, 0.0520203 - 8.87099 \mathrm{i}, \\
0.21055 - 6.15455 \mathrm{i}, 0.456226 - 3.46775 \mathrm{i}, \\
0.877125 - 0.9958 \mathrm{i}, 0.877125 + 0.9958 \mathrm{i}, \\
0.456226 + 3.46775 \mathrm{i}, 0.21055 + 6.15455 \mathrm{i}, \\
0.0520203 + 8.87099 \mathrm{i}, -0.0642696 + 11.5948 \mathrm{i}, \\
-0.156006 + 14.3212 \mathrm{i}, \dots\}  \text{.}$

I'm pretty sure the first solution ($n=a=1$) is the only solution over the reals, but I haven't checked to see if there's an unexpected all real solution from the $W_k$s.

Comment: So what am I doing wrong when I say $a = 2$ then $2/n = n^2$ so $2 = n^3$ so $a = 2; n = \sqrt[3] 2$ is a solution.  $2/\sqrt[3]2 = \sqrt[3]2^2$.

Comment: @fleablood : You mean other than ignoring the other two solutions: $-\sqrt[3]{-2}$ and $(-1)^{2/3} 2^{1/3}$?

Comment: I didn't ignore them.  You claimed that n = a = 1 is the only solution on the reals.  Unless I made a mistake, that isn't true as  I claim a=2; n= cuberoot(2) is also a solution.  I certainly *never* claimed it was the *only* other solution.  In fact in my answer I claimed all positive a and all negative a where 1/(a+1) is rational with an odd demonator were solutions.  So there are certainly more solutions than just the 4 you listed.

Comment: I don't see that I claimed $"n=a=1"$ is the only solution in the reals.  I see that I claimed that "I haven't checked".

Comment: Okay, you didn't claim it was the only solution; you claimed you were pretty sure it was the only solution.  I should clarify my statement "That is true that your are pretty sure but unless I made a mistake you are mistaken in such sureity as I believe I have demonstrated your belief to be false."  Better?